# Create a Table of data type, unique values for all columns in a data frame in Python

Tags: python

I have the following data frame:

```
# importing pandas
import pandas as pd

# Making a df data frame 
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'letter': ['a','b','c','a','b','c'],
    'state': ['CA','FL','CA','FL','CA','FL'],
    'scores': [11.6,12.8,13.9,14.2,15.8,16.2],
    'age': [12,28,19,14,12,28]})
df
```

I would like to write a code in Python, where my desired output is as followed:

| columns_names | Dtype | Unique_values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| letter | object | a,b,c |
| state | object | CA, FL |
| scores | float | 11.6, 12.8, 13.9, 14.2, 15.8, 16.2 |
| age | integer | 12, 28, 19, 14 |

---

What can I do to construct a summary table like that? I know this is a short example, but ideally I would like a function that can apply to an entire df (say 70 columns for example). Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your minimum example, you can create a new dataframe by looping through the columns of the dataframe and calculating the unique counts:

```
arr, arr2 = [], []
for col in df.columns:
  temp = [str(x) for x in df[col].unique()] # convert to str
  arr.append(','.join(temp))
  arr2.append(len(temp))

pd.DataFrame({'column': df.columns, 'dtype':df.dtypes.to_list() ,'unique_vals':arr, 'count': arr2})
```

Output:

```
   column    dtype                    unique_vals  count
0  letter   object                          a,b,c      3
1   state   object                          CA,FL      2
2  scores  float64  11.6,12.8,13.9,14.2,15.8,16.2      6
3     age    int64                    12,28,19,14      4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I like your way. It is very simple and straightforward.

Comment: Another question: if I were to add another column called 'Number of Unique values'. How would I implement that into your code? For example, the no_unique_values would be: 3, 2, 6, 4 (count of how many unique values each columns have).

Comment: 2 ways; either while generating you create a new array with `len(temp)` [see edit] or you use `df2['unique_vals'].str.split(',').apply(len)`

Comment: Thank you very much Suraj. You are the best!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
uniq = pd.DataFrame([{c: ",".join(map(str, df[c].unique())) for c in df.columns}]).T[0]
final_df = pd.concat({"Dtype": df.dtypes, "Unique_values": uniq}, axis=1)
print(final_df)
```

Prints:

```
          Dtype                  Unique_values
letter   object                          a,b,c
state    object                          CA,FL
scores  float64  11.6,12.8,13.9,14.2,15.8,16.2
age       int64                    12,28,19,14
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out

```js
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'letter': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
    'state': ['CA', 'FL', 'CA', 'FL', 'CA', 'FL'],
    'scores': [11.6, 12.8, 13.9, 14.2, 15.8, 16.2],
    'age': [12, 28, 19, 14, 12, 28]
})


unique_values = df.apply(lambda col: col.unique()).transpose()


print(unique_values)
```